# Preciso fazer um Select em 3 tabelas diferentes e não sei como fazer

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, select

Seguinte preciso fazer uma consulta nas seguintes condições:

- Preciso dos dados da tabela `A` (`Numero`, `Ano`, `vencimento`, `Nome`);
- buscando a informação de *não recebido* na coluna `Recebimento` da tabela `B`;
- e preciso que a coluna `Numero` da tabela `A` **não esteja** na tabela `C`

Fiz algo assim, mas não rolou

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table A
WHERE a.NUMERO > 100 
AND a.ANO BETWEEN '01-JAN-2019' AND '01-JAN-2021' A.VENCIMENTO 
AND A.NOME 
AND b.RECEBIMENTO IS NULL IN (SELECT TABLE b) 
AND a.NUMERO IS NOT  IN (SELECT c.NUMERO 
                         FROM  TABLE C 
                         WHERE c.ANO = a.ANO)
```

Comment: Esse trecho "AND b.RECEBIMENTO IS NULL IN (SELECT TABLE b) ", o "b.RECEBIMENTO" não vai encontrar a tabela B pois não esta relacionada no select principal  pode ter sido um erro de digitação

Comment: Qual é o banco de dados? Pode adicionar a pergunta o sql das tabelas?

Answer (score 1):

A consulta apresenta algumas inconsistências a serem sanadas:

1. `FROM Table A` deve ser `FROM A`
2. `AND a.ANO BETWEEN '01-JAN-2019' AND '01-JAN-2021' A.VENCIMENTO`
   pode ser `and A.VENCIMENTO BETWEEN '01-01-2019' AND '01-03-2021'`
3. note que alterei de `'JAN'` para `'01'`.
4. `A.VENCIMENTO` veio para antes do `BETWEEN`
5. `AND A.NOME` isolado não faz sentido, pois precisa ser uma expressão que verifique algo.

Segue uma consulta que pode ser utilizada.

```
select a.* 
  from a left join b on a.numero = b.numero 
where a.NUMERO > 100 
  and A.VENCIMENTO BETWEEN '01-01-2019' AND '01-03-2021'
  and b.recebimento is null
  and not exists (select * from c where c.numero = a.numero and c.ano = a.ano)
```

- Primeiro foi realizada a união entre as tabelas `a` e `b`.
- Visto que as tabelas foram unidas, usamos na cláusula `where` o trecho `and b.recebimento is null` para excluir dos resultados as tuplas que não satisfazem esse requisito.
- Depois verificamos a não existência dos dados da tabela `c` em relação a tabela `a` para satisfazer esse outro requisito.